# How can I add video time to ffmpeg filename?

Tags: linux, image, video, ffmpeg, video-capture

I'm extracting frames from a video at 1 frame every 5 seconds using

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -r 0.2 frames/frame_%04d.png
```

and I want to add in-video time (ie. time elapsed since beginning of video at x1 speed) to the filename (not timestamp like asked in related questions). Something that could be like

```
frame_0001_0000.png, frame_0002_0005.png, frame_0003_0010.png, ...
# would stand for
# frame #1 at 00:00, frame #2 at 00:05, frame #3 at 00:10, ...
```

Since the ffmpeg prints this information while processing, I thought this would be possible? I don't want to rely on (frame_number * 1/r) since there are usually a few extra frames making the result off.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: "in-video time" but "not timestamp".

Comment: I mean time elapsed since the beginning of video (when watching at 1x speed) such as `00:37` and not timestamp such as `2020-11-18T04:16:12`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible right now. There is however an abandoned ticket+patch that added this functionality to ffmpeg some years ago.

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1452

You should be able to salvage that patch, but it may need some modifications given ffmpeg has evolved since then.